# Why isn't this Google Apps script autosorting on open?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets that registers the entries from a Google Form. I set up a script to autosort the sheet every time the sheet is opened and a trigger to run the script on open, but no sorting is happening. I've limited knowledge of scripting and javascript. What's wrong with the following script?

```
function OrderByEvent() {
// The numeric index of the column you wish to keep auto-sorted. A = 1, B = 2,
// and so on.
var SORT_COLUMN_INDEX = 10;
// Whether to sort the data in ascending or descending order. false=ascending and true=descending
var ASCENDING = true;
// If you have header rows in your sheet, specify how many to exclude them from
// the sort.
var NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS = 1;

// No need to edit anything below this line for general use.
// Make an improvement? Ping me on GitHub and let me know!

// Keep track of the active sheet.
var activeSheet;

/**
 * Automatically sorts on the pre-defined column.
 *
 * @param {Sheet} sheet The sheet to sort.
 */
function autoSort(sheet) {
  // Get the entire set of data for this sheet.
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  // Then, if there are any header rows, offset our range to remove them from
  // it; otherwise, they will end up being sorted as well.
  if (NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS > 0) {
    // Setting the second parameter of offset() to 0 to prevents it from
    // shifting any columns. Note that row headers wouldn't make much
    // sense here, but this is where you would modify it if you
    // wanted support for those as well.
    range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);
  }

  // Perform the actual sort.
  range.sort( {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  } );
}

function onOpen(event) {
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  {autoSort(activeSheet);
  }
}

/**
 * Triggers when a sheet is edited, and calls the auto sort function if the
 * edited cell is in the column we're looking to sort.
 *
 * @param {Object} event The triggering event.
 */

//function onEdit(event) {
//  var editedCell;

  // Update the active sheet in case it changed.
//  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Get the cell that was just modified.
//  editedCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();

  // Only trigger a re-sort if the user edited data in the column they're
  // sorting by; otherwise, we perform unnecessary additional sorts if
  // the targeted sort column's data didn't change.
//  if (editedCell.getColumn() == SORT_COLUMN_INDEX) {
//    autoSort(activeSheet);
//  }
//}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the function of `onOpen()` which is used as a simple trigger is been putting in a function of `OrderByEvent()`. By this, when the Spreadsheet is opened, `onOpen()` is not run. Even when `OrderByEvent()` is installed as the installable trigger, when `OrderByEvent()` is run, `onOpen()` is not run.

  - By this, the script for sorting is not run.
- When the OnOpen event trigger is used, you can use the event object.

  - For example, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` can be modified to `event.source` in your script. Of course, `event.source.getActiveSheet()` can be used.
  - When event object is used, the process cost can be reduced. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4892c97df7ac0504ffd715c2dd6cd546)

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

```
function autoSort(sheet) {
  var SORT_COLUMN_INDEX = 10;
  var ASCENDING = true;
  var NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS = 1;
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  if (NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS > 0) {
    range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);
  }
  range.sort( {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  } );
}

function onOpen(event) {
  autoSort(event.source);
}
```

- In your script, the script can work using the simple trigger. So in this case, it is not required to install the installable trigger. `onOpen()` is automatically run and works when the Spreadsheet is opened.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your sort script works.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Benchmark: Event Objects for Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4892c97df7ac0504ffd715c2dd6cd546)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @To Do Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.